# FCK Editor not loading in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fckeditor

We have a JSP page where we have some buttons. On click of a button a jquery popup (or a dialog box) is opened. The pop up has a form in it which has a FCK editor.

When the form is submitted, the pop up is closed and the state on the JSP page is refreshed.

You can again open same pop up by clicking button on page. You can repeat this n times.

During this process, some times this FCK editor does not render on the pop up in the Firefox. i.e. If you click a button on JSP, a pop up is opened, FCK editor is not displayed at all. It shows a blank space in place of FCK editor.

It works properly in IE.

The version of the Firefox that we are testing on is 3.6.15.

The FCK editor version is 2.6.

While googling on the issue I came across following link

[FCKEditor Year 2010 Bug for Firefox 3.6 with ColdFusion](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/737.cfm)

Its in cold fusion though. We are using Struts 2 and JSP.

We are having this problem for lot of time now. Any hints or clues will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @experimentX, it will require whole lot of changes to move from FCK to CK as we have customized the FCK to certain extent.

Comment: I think FCK editor has embedded server file browser maybe thats where you get error. I am not sure if FCK supports jsp. please check for it again.

Comment: The FCK works properly in IE. Even in fire fox if I use FCK on simple JSP (not in pop up) it works fine. Its creating problem in fire fox and that too in pop ups only. I think it has something to do with opening a pop up even before the under lying JSP is not loaded completely. This is where its creating problems most of the time.

Comment: Is there any way we can make sure that the user will not be able to click the buttons untill the JSP is fully loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue basically here in this case is that the if you try to open a from which has FCKEditor even before your page has loaded completely, the FCKEditor will not render.

I just disabled the buttons which opens the pop (which contains FCK Editor) until the page is completely loaded and once it is loaded buttons are enables.

Clicking on buttons opens the form in which FCK Editor is rendered properly now.